# python3 script as subprocess in python2, empty PIPE

Tags: python, subprocess, fcntl

i made this two script to illustrate my problem.

I want a python2 script to have a python3 script as as subprocess with a non blocking read.

Lets say both scripts are in the /tmp folder

The child python3 script is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
while True:
    print ("test")
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

And the parent script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import fcntl
import os
import subprocess
import time

sub = subprocess.Popen(['python3','/tmp/child.py'], cwd='/tmp', bufsize=1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

fcntl.fcntl(sub.stdout.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)

while True:
    try:
        print sub.stdout.read() #Thats the not working part
    except IOError:
        pass
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

The parent script does not get the output from the child process, and i get no output to stdout either.
So the output gets redirected, but its basically lost.
This is not intended.
How do i get the output from the child process ?
In my real script the output from the child script gets processed in the parent script instead of printed.

thank you for help.

Comment: Do you need to call `Popen.communicate`? See https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline

Comment: @Xvolks Should i just swap the read line with a communicate line ? because that did not work.

Comment: I’m not a Python expert, I’ve just pointed the doc. If the doc’s implementation does not work for you, the problem is probably elsewhere.